# Problem of students in class

Tags: graph-theory

a classroom with odd numbers of students. Suppose that each student has at least one people friend and if any two students have common people friends then they  have numbers different friends.
a) Prove that always find a student with exactly 3 friends.
b) The above assertion is true if we replace 3 by 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a graph  whose vertices are students and two vertices are adjacent if they are friends.

a) Let $v$ be a vertex of maximal degree $d$. Suppose to the contrary that $d\le 2$. Then $G$ is a union of paths and cycles. But any cycle and path of order distinct from $2$ and $4$ contains two vertices with a common neighbor and a common number of neighbors. Thus $G$ is a union of paths of even order and so $G$ has an even number of vertices, a contradiction. Thus $d\ge 3$. Since $d$ neighbors of $v$ have distinct degress from $1$ to $d$, one of them has degree $3$.

b) The modified assertion can be false as the following example shows.

[image]